# Proof Check: The Sum-of-Positive-Divisors Function is Multiplicative

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I was wondering whether someone could check my proof. Thank you.

**Theorem**. The function $\sigma{(n)}=\sum\limits_{d|n}d$ is multiplicative.

*Proof.* Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $(m,n)=1$. From the FTA we may write

$$
m=p_{1}^{k_{1}}...p_{r}^{k_{r}} \text{$\ \ \ \ \ $and$\ \ \ \ \ $}n=q_{1}^{l_{1}}...q_{s}^{l_{s}},\text{$\ \ \ \ \ $}p_{i},q_{i}\in\mathbb{P}.
$$
Now let
$$
p_{r+1}^{k_{r+1}}=q_{1}^{l_{1}}\\
\vdots\\
p_{r+s}^{k_{r+s}}=q_{s}^{l_{s}}
$$
We have

\begin{align}
\sigma{(mn)}&=\sum\limits_{j_{r+s}=0}^{k_{r+s}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{k_{1}}\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{r+s}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\\
\quad&=\prod\limits_{i=0}^{r+s}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{i}}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\\
\quad&=\Big[\prod\limits_{i=0}^{r}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{i}}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\Big]\Big[\prod\limits_{i=r+1}^{r+s}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{i}}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\Big]\\
\quad&=\Big[\prod\limits_{i=0}^{r}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{i}}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\Big]\Big[\prod\limits_{i=1}^{s}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{l_{i}}q_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\Big]\\
\quad&=\sigma(m)\sigma(n).
\end{align}QED

Comment: Looks correct other than the typo already noted by @DonaldSplutterwit . I'd suggest a few more words explaining the thought process in obtaining the last few equalities.

Comment: @JoshuaZ Could you tell me which lines you would like me to tell you about?

Comment: The second to last equality in particular would one where I think some additional explanation would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct; here's a simpler proof: suppose $r = mn$ where $(m,n)=1$. The divisors of $m$ are $a_0=1, a_1,\dotsc, a_s = m$; the divisors of $n$ are $b_0=1, b_1,\dotsc, b_t=n$. Then each divisor of $r$ is of the form $a_ib_j$, since $(m,n)=1$. Thus the sum of the divisors of $r$ is
$$\sigma(mn)=\sum_{i,j} a_ib_j = \sum_i a_i\sum_j b_j = \sigma(m)\sigma(n).$$

Comment: Well yes, but first you have to prove that you can express all divisors of $r$ as products $a_{i}b_{i}$, no?

Comment: I suppose, yes, but if $d\min r$, then since $(a,b)=1$ isn't is clear that $(d,a)(d,b)=d$? If you wish, you can prove that by factoring $a$ and $b$.