# Proof Check: If $f$ is multiplicative then $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}f(d)$ is also multiplicative.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I asked a similar question here: 
[Proof Check: The Sum-of-Positive-Divisors Function is Multiplicative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3464143)
Hope it doesn't get counted as a duplicate.

---

**Theorem**. If $f$ is multiplicative then $F(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}f(d)$ is also multiplicative.

*Proof.* Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $(m,n)=1$. From the FTA we may write

$$
m=p_{1}^{k_{1}}...p_{r}^{k_{r}} \text{$\ \ \ \ \ $and$\ \ \ \ \ $}n=q_{1}^{l_{1}}...q_{s}^{l_{s}},\text{$\ \ \ \ \ $}p_{i},q_{i}\in\mathbb{P}.
$$
Now let
$$
p_{r+1}^{k_{r+1}}=q_{1}^{l_{1}}\\
\vdots\\
p_{r+s}^{k_{r+s}}=q_{s}^{l_{s}}
$$
We have

\begin{align}
F{(mn)}&=\sum\limits_{j_{r+s}=0}^{k_{r+s}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{k_{1}}f\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{r+s}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\\
\quad&=\sum\limits_{j_{r+s}=0}^{k_{r+s}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{k_{1}}\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{r+s}f(p_{i}^{j_{i}})\big)\\
\quad&=\prod\limits_{i=0}^{r+s}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{I}}f(p_{i}^{j_{I}})\big)\\
\quad&=\Big[\prod\limits_{i=0}^{r}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{I}}f(p_{i}^{j_{i}})\big)\Big]\Big[\prod\limits_{i=r+1}^{r+s}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{I}}f(p_{i}^{j_{i}})\big)\Big]\\
\quad&=\Big[\prod\limits_{i=0}^{r}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{k_{I}}f(p_{i}^{j_{i}})\big)\Big]\Big[\prod\limits_{i=1}^{s}\big(\sum\limits_{j_{i}=0}^{l_{I}}f(q_{i}^{j_{I}})\big)\Big]\\
\quad&=\Big[\sum\limits_{j_{r}=0}^{k_{r}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{k_{1}}\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{r}f(p_{i}^{j_{i}})\big)\Big]\Big[\sum\limits_{j_{s}=0}^{l_{s}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{l_{1}}\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{s}f(q_{i}^{j_{i}})\big)\Big]\\
\quad&=\Big[\sum\limits_{j_{r}=0}^{k_{r}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{k_{1}}f\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{r}p_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\Big]\Big[\sum\limits_{j_{s}=0}^{l_{s}}\dots\sum\limits_{j_{1}=0}^{l_{1}}f\big(\prod\limits_{i=1}^{s}q_{i}^{j_{i}}\big)\Big]\\
\quad&=F(m)F(n).
\end{align}QED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a bit simpler: if $n = n_1 n_2$ with $n_1$ and $n_2$ coprime, then $d | n$ iff $d = d_1 d_2$ where $d_1 | n_1$ and $d_2 | n_2$.  Of course $d_1$ and $d_2$ are coprime. So 
$$\sum_{d | n} f(d) = \sum_{d_1 | n_1} \sum_{d_2 | n_2} f(d_1 d_2) = \sum_{d_1 | n_1} \sum_{d_2|n_2} f(d_1) f(d_2) = \left(\sum_{d_1 | n_1} f(d_1)\right) \left(\sum_{d_2 | n_2} f(d_2)\right) $$